# How to select static text with LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a listbox and I want its ItemsSource to be all the items of an ObservableCollection + an additional static text such as "All Items."

Right now I just have something similar to:

```
listbox1.ItemsSource = from Car c in Cars
                       select c.Model
```

I know I could just manually add the text to the listbox, but I want it to be part of the query because the linq query is bound using the Obtics library (so the UI updates reactively). I am not too familiar with linq queries outside the basics, so does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Union() operator to add more objects into your selected set.

```
string[] additionalItems = {"All Items"};

listbox1.ItemsSource = (from Car c in Cars
                       select c.Model)
                       .Union(additionalItems);
```

Comment: In the Union clause, `from s in additionalItems select s` is redundant: just `additionalItems` has the same effect and is more concise.

Comment: Yeah I just realized my initial example was poor.  Was editing it as you commented ;)